# how to add validation for phone number in kendo ui for angular

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

i'm using reactive forms,unable to add validation like length,and it allows  more than 10 digit can anyone give me full solution i'm using reactive forms.and there is any validation for numbers length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contact = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{10,12}$")]);
```

Regex: `^[0-9]{10,12}$`

Where,

[0,9]   - Accept 0 to 9 numbers
{10,12} - Range